# SELECT A, B, C, GMTDATE FROM TABLE_NAME: with constant GMT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 SELECT A, B, C, GMTDATE 
   FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Here when Data is large.

```
     A  B  C             GMTDATE
    X1 Y1 Z1 2017.06.05.17:17:59
    X2 Y2 Z2 2017.06.05.17:17:59
    X3 Y3 Z3 2017.06.05.17:17:59
    X4 Y4 Z4 2017.06.05.17:18:00
```

Exmplanation:  I want same GMT date for all data. 
Then GMT Date will be different at every second in the table: it display's time of at the time of execution. Where I want same GMTDATE for ALL Data. Either it should be GMT DATE of starting of execution the query or Execution end of the query.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you illustrate by providing sample date and desired result?

Comment: @P.Salmon, OP wants the same GMTDATE value returned for all rows, but gets a second increment between two rows.

Comment: Yes I want same GMTDATE for all rows

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B, C, DT.gmtvalue
   FROM TABLE_NAME, (select GMTDATE gmtvalue) DT
```

Comment: This is also give same result.

Comment: SELECT A, B, C, DT.gmtvalue
       FROM TABLE_NAME, (select GMTDATE as gmtvalue from dual) DT, as it was giving error.

Comment: Right. For PostgreSQL, SQLServer, no need to refer to a table like dual.